# 'alt' key stuck while using ALT-TAB in Remoteapp

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, remoteapp

Im using Microsoft's remote app installed on Server 2012 R2 and windows 10 client. While moving between the local windows and the remote windows (with  ALT-TAB) the alt key gets stuck on the **remote window** and released only after pressing any random key.

After investigating this problem i found out that it happens only in windows 10 and its related to the client RDP version (10+). In Windows 7 this problem does not appear (RDP 8.0). I also tried to install Server 2016 and this problem this exists.

I'm looking for a solution to this problem, and there is nothing useful on google result.

Comment: Possibly related: [While in a remote desktop session in Windows 7, alt-tab to go back to the host machine](https://superuser.com/a/728389)  The suggestion there is to use ctrl+alt+break to leave fullscreen rdp and then alt-tab. Another possibly related one: [Remote Desktop and ALT-TAB not working](https://superuser.com/a/1199264) – This one says to check your Local Resources tab in both local and remote computers that Keyboard setting is set to "Only when using the full screen."

Comment: I'v tried this suggestion, because I'm using RemoteApp instead Full Screen this solution is not so relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was driving me nuts, but, after some digging, I found a solution: use the old Windows 7 client on Windows 10 machine.
If you don't have access to a Windows 7 machine, just download KB2592687, it contains all the necessary files. You'll have to extract the package - use expand.exe

The files you'll need are the following:

mstsc.exe
mstscax.dll

And the corresponding mui files for the previous two files:

mstsc.exe.mui
mstscax.dll.mui

which correspond to the language of your Windows 10 installation.
The mui files need to be placed in the lang code folder: for example, if you have an English version of Windows 10 installed, then put the mui files into en-US folder.
Start the client in the folder you copied the above files to and connect to the remote computer.